# Locating specific img with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I'm trying to download the post on the Instagram page, but every time Selenium selects and downloads the profile photo.

```
    def downloadPost(self,link):
     os.system("cls")
     self.link = link
     self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(self.drvPath, chrome_options=self.browserProfile)
     self.browser.get(link)
     time.sleep(2)
     img = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
     src = img.get_attribute('src')
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, f"{self.imgPath}/igpost.png")
     self.browser.close()
```

The photo tag I want to capture is under the second img tag and I can't identify it.

[html code that I try to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbl3U.png)

Comment: have you tried to use findall with css-classes? or instead you can use www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1 and then use regex in the text

Comment: Just use find_elements and then index the 2nd element [1] or use xpath //img[@alt=''] or even //div/img as an xpath would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this. By grabbing 2nd img tag or the first div with img child class.

```
self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")[1]

self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div/img")

self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@alt='whateverattributevalueithas']")
```